# Nested do.call within a foreach %dopar% environment can't find function passed with .export

Tags: r, foreach, do.call, doparallel

I am nesting multiple levels of `do.call` (each themselves using functions named in the parameters, not hard-coded) within a `%dopar%` parallelized environment, and a function from my outside environment can't be found by the innermost function. I know about the `.export` parameter on `foreach` and am using it, but somehow the named function isn't propagating down the entire chain.

I reduced my issue to the following test case, which does exhibit this problem:

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)

simple.func <- function(a, b) {
  return(a+b)
}

inner.func <- function(a, b) {
  return(do.call(simple.func, list(a=a, b=b)))
}

outer.func <- function(a, b, my.func=inner.func) {
  return(do.call(my.func, list(a=a, b=b)))
}

main.func <- function(my.list=1:10, my.func=outer.func,
                      my.args=list(my.func=inner.func)) {
  results <- foreach(i=my.list, .multicombine=TRUE, .inorder=FALSE,
                     .export="simple.func") %dopar% {
    return(do.call(my.func, c(list(a=i, b=i+1), my.args)))
  }
  return(results)
}
```

Rather than giving the correct answer (a list with some numbers), I get:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'simple.func' not found"
```

Adding `if (!exists("simple.func")) stop("Could not find parse.data in scope main.func")` to the start of each function (changing the name of the scope as appropriate) reveals that it's `inner.func` which doesn't see `simple.func` -- even though `outer.func` *does* see it.

I also tested a couple of variations of the above, with either `main.func` or `outer.func` having the next-level function hard-coded, rather than using it from a parameter. Both of these variations *do* work (e.g., give the expected result), but for the real-world case I want to retain the generalizability of taking the sub-functions as parameters.

```
# Variation number one: Replace main.func() with this version
main.func <- function(my.list=1:10, my.func=outer.func,
                      my.args=list(my.func=inner.func)) {
  results <- foreach(i=my.list, .multicombine=TRUE, .inorder=FALSE,
                     .export=c("simple.func", "outer.func", "inner.func")) %dopar% {
    return(do.call(outer.func, list(a=i, b=i+1, my.func=inner.func)))
  }
  return(results)
}

# Variation number two: Replace outer.func() and main.func() with these versions
outer.func <- function(a, b, my.func=inner.func) {
  return(do.call(inner.func, list(a=a, b=b)))
}

main.func <- function(my.list=1:10, my.func=outer.func,
                      my.args=list(my.func=inner.func)) {
  results <- foreach(i=my.list, .multicombine=TRUE, .inorder=FALSE,
                     .export=c("simple.func", "inner.func")) %dopar% {
    return(do.call(my.func, c(list(a=i, b=i+1), my.args)))
  }
  return(results)
}
```

I could also pass `simple.func` down the chain manually, by including it as an extra parameter, but this looks extra messy, and why should it be necessary when `simple.func` should just be passed along as part of the environment?

```
# Variation number three: Replace inner.func(), outer.func(), and main.func()
# with these versions
inner.func <- function(a, b, innermost.func=simple.func) {
  return(do.call(innermost.func, list(a=a, b=b)))
}

outer.func <- function(a, b, my.func=inner.func,
                       innermost.args=list(innermost.func=simple.func)) {
  return(do.call(my.func, c(list(a=a, b=b), innermost.args)))
}

main.func <- function(my.list=1:10, my.func=outer.func,
                      my.args=list(my.func=inner.func,
                      innermost.args=list(innermost.func=simple.func))) {
  results <- foreach(i=my.list, .multicombine=TRUE, .inorder=FALSE,
                     .export="simple.func") %dopar% {
    return(do.call(my.func, c(list(a=i, b=i+1), my.args)))
  }
  return(results)
}
```

Does anyone have ideas for less-kludgy solutions, or the underlying cause of this problem?

Comment: Just a note since your code is full of them: all of the `return` calls are unnecessary. R automatically returns the value of the last expression in a function. You only need `return` to leave a function prematurely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `doParallel`, and any other `doNnn` adaptor that doesn't fork the current process, I think the following *hack* would do it:

```
main.func <- function(my.list = 1:10, my.func=outer.func,
                      my.args = list(my.func=inner.func)) {
  results <- foreach(i = my.list, .multicombine = TRUE, .inorder = FALSE,
                     .export="simple.func") %dopar% {
    environment(my.args$my.func) <- environment()  ## <= HACK
    return(do.call(my.func, args = c(list(a=i, b=i+1), my.args)))
  }
  return(results)
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [doFuture](https://cran.r-project.org/package=doFuture) adaptor (I'm the author).  Then you don't have to worry about global objects because they are automatically identified and exported.  That is, there is no need for specifying `.export` (or `.packages`).  For example, in your case the following works:

```
library("doFuture")
registerDoFuture()
plan(multisession, workers = 4)

main.func <- function(my.list = 1:10, my.func = outer.func,
                      my.args = list(my.func = inner.func)) {
  foreach(i = my.list, .multicombine = TRUE, .inorder = FALSE) %dopar% {
    do.call(my.func, args = c(list(a = i, b = i+1), my.args))
  }
}

res <- main.func(1:3)
str(res)
## List of 10
##  $ : num 3
##  $ : num 5
##  $ : num 7
```

You can also skip `foreach()` all along and do:

```
library("future")
plan(multisession, workers = 4)

main <- function(my.list = 1:10, my.func = outer.func,
                 my.args = list(my.func = inner.func)) {
  future_lapply(my.list, FUN = function(i) {
    do.call(my.func, args = c(list(a = i, b = i+1), my.args))
  })
}
```

PS. There are lots of different `plan()` backends to choose from.  The only one that is not covered is if you use `doRedis`.

Comment: The environment() hack seems to work, but using your doFuture library sometimes gives the following error (when running plan(cluster, workers=cl) to load a cluster): "Error in UseMethod("tweak") : no applicable method for 'tweak' applied to an object of class "function"".
Is there an easy answer for this, or should I open a new question (or submit a bug to your GitHub)?

Comment: Hmm... could it be that you attached another package defining another `cluster` function? What does `str(cluster)` say it belongs to?  Does `plan("cluster", workers = cl)` or `plan(future::cluster, workers = cl)` fix it?  If not, please create an issue on https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future about this so we can figure out what's going on. Thxs for letting me know.